# Why Classful addressing is not in use if we can subnet them?

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address, layer3

So,

Let's think that organization needs 5000 IP addresses. Giving 20 C Class IP addresses will cause of adding 20 entries for ISP router. That's problem. We could give Class B IP address, but that will also cause problem, because of waste IP addresses.

We can subnet Class B IP address. For example, Class B IP address is 130.168.0.0. We allocate organization with 130.168.0.0/19 block of Class B IP address (32 subnetworks). So ISP router will add just one entry for 130.168.0.0/19.

It seems, everything works.

1) Why it was decided to not use Classful addressing, **if we can subnet them**?

2) Can there happen some grand issues or move to CIDR is due to flexibility or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We can subnet Class B IP address. For example, Class B IP address is
>   130.168.0.0. We allocate organization with 130.168.0.0/20 block of Class B IP address (32 subnetworks). So ISP router will add just one
>   entry for 130.168.0.0/20.

That *is* classless routing. Classful routing means that the entire Class B network can only be used by the domain (company) assigned the network. Classful addressing cannot be subnetted between domains (Inter-Domain). Routing happens by the network class, and that means only one domain can have the addressing in the network and class.

What you propose *is* CIDR (*Classless* Inter-Domain Routing). It allows the flexibility to assign a domain only part of a classful network.

> 1) Why it was decided to not use Classful addressing, **if we can
>   subnet them**?

You can subnet a classful network within a domain, but not between domains.

> 2) Can there happen some grand issues or move to CIDR is due to
>   flexibility or something like that?

A company needing only 300 addresses would need to be assigned a Class B network (65,536 addresses) under classful routing, wasting over 99% of the addresses in the network class. With CIDR, the company could be assigned a `/23` network, regardless of the initial network bits (part of an old Class A or B network, or an aggregated pair of old Class C networks), and waste far fewer addresses.

Comment: What if ISP has a block of class B IP address 130.168.0.0. Can't ISP subnet within domain like 130.168.0.0/19 and assign that to organization. Wouldn't it be subnetting within a domain? So router in ISP will look at subnet mask after it gets datagram by classful routing. I know, it is actually Classless addressing, but again, if ISP can subnet network within a domain, why we've switched to Classless addressing.

Comment: Yes, but you are forgetting that many companies have provider-independent addressing. IP addresses are assigned to companies, and ISPs are just companies.

Comment: NO. *Everything* is either classful or not. There is no subnetting in a classful system -- the netmask depends *entirely* on the address; it's not even configurable. I know it's hard to grasp as true classful systems haven't been around for decades.

Comment: @RickyBeam, even the original classful RIPv1 allows subnetting within a domain, but all the subnets are required to be exactly the same size. It was the EGP (inter-domain) routing that could not be subnetted.

Comment: @RickyBeam, subnetting within domains are possible according to TCP/IP Guide.